# What does objConnectionVS.Execute do and if there are replacements for the same function

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, vbscript

I have a user-defined function that queries a MS Access database, and it is very slow. I drilled down the line that is causing the issue, and it turns out to be the following: `Set rsTable = objConnectionVS.Execute(strSQL)`. StrSQL is a string of SQL code.

The function takes about 1 second to run, and every other line returned 0 seconds with the timer function. (Thus I assume this line is the problem).

I did some google search and could not find the exact function `objConnectionVS`. I was able to find `objConnection`, but deleting the "VS" causes an error.

I am wondering if there are some resources where I can look up the function, and also if there are replacements for the `objConnectionVS` that is faster.

Lastly, I wonder if switching to SQL Server will be feasible and whether it'd be much faster (assuming that I still use Excel to query). And how much time and effort will it take to move database to SQL Server and set up queries in Excel (I have no knowledge of SQL or SQL Server and will need to start from scratch, but I only need to run some SQL code from Excel).

Comment: that sql query should not perform faster, or slower then any other query. So, that one sql statement being slow is likely  due to the sql statement. Check indexing etc.  Dlookup() or creating executing a sql statement  is not slow, but if you repeating  the command in some loop, then sure, it going to be slow, but no slower then any other single query. The trick is then to execute one query as opposed to many.

Comment: `obConnectionVS` is (presumably) an ADO connection to your database. `Execute()` is a method for executing SQL statements over that connection. If there is a problem then it's most likely with the SQL query, not the `Execute()` method itself. Try running the statement directly in Access for comparison.